# Display the content of a HTML file on a HTML page onclick of link

Tags: jquery, html, datagrid

I have a HTML file in **my local directory C:** and I want to provide a link on my HTML page named **status** which on click  displays the contents of the HTML file(having a data grid table)  on the HTML page.

Can anyone suggest me how can I achieve this?

**P.S:** Below is the code for the HTML file having the datagrid and I want to display it on a plain HTML page onclick of a link named Status.

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Server status</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.jeasyui.com/easyui/themes/default/easyui.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.jeasyui.com/easyui/themes/icon.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.jeasyui.com/easyui/jquery.easyui.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <table id="tt" class="easyui-datagrid" style="width:380px;height:auto;">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th field="name1" width="80">Status</th>                
            </tr>                          
        </thead>                           
        <tbody>                            
            <tr>                           
                <td>Australia</td>                      
            </tr>                          
            <tr>                           
                <td>Canada</td>                        
            </tr>                          
            <tr>                           
                   <td>USA</td>                                     
            </tr>                          
            <tr>                           
                <td>UK</td>                       
            </tr>                          
        </tbody>                           
    </table>        
</body>
</html>
```

**Problem code**

```
<html>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.2.6.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript"> 
 $(document).ready(function() {

   $('.click').on("click", function(e){
        e.preventDefault(); // cancel the default a tag event.

        $.get( "datagrid.html", function( data ) {
          $(".result").html( data );
        });

   });
 });
</script>
<body style="background-color:gray;">
<div id="wrapper">

  <div id="tabContainer">
    <div id="tabs">
      <ul>
        <li id="tabHeader_1">Status</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="tabscontent">
      <div class="tabpage" id="tabpage_1">
      <marquee behavior="scroll" bgcolor="yellow" loop="-1" width="35%"><i><font color="Red"><strong>One server is down...</strong></font></i></marquee>   
     <a href="http://localhost:8080/monitor/datagrid.html" class="click"><font color="Black">click me</font></a>
<div class="result"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You could use jQuery's `get()` method - http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/ and then append that HTML to the page.

Comment: I am completely new to Jquery concepts, can you give some example or sample code for my above code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this:

HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="click">click me </a>
<div class="result"></div>
```

jQuery

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {

   $('.click').on("click", function(e){
        e.preventDefault(); // cancel the default a tag event.

        $.get( "my-file.html", function( data ) {
          $(".result").html( data );
        });

   });
 });
</script>
```

Explaination :

We have a link, which has a click event bound to it, and then on click, we will make an Ajax request to our `.html` file, and then we append the `data` returned to the `results` div,

NOTE: For this to work - you need to run this via a web-server (Like WAMP), and not via the `file://` protocol.

Comment: I tried using http://localhost:8080/monitor/datagrid.html in the link <a href = "http://localhost:8080/monitor/datagrid.html" class"click"> but it didnt work for me. Am I doing something wrong by hosting my html file datagrid in apache tomcat app server?

Comment: @ScriptLearner Can you update your post with the latest code that you're using - thanks.

Comment: I have added the code section I am using the suggested script in the section: Problem Code in my original post thread

Comment: The version of jQuery you're using was released in 2008, you might want to try the latest version ;-)